# getting bsod 0x000003b in random times

Tags: windows-7, bsod

so i recently began getting bsods in random times with the code 0x0000003b it happens like 2 times a week , i checked for missing files and there is none , tested the memory no errors found,no malwares, and i have the latest drivers.

i have : windows 7 ultimate 64bit

and i've uploaded the minidump:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/zeukp6g2pczel86/081621-26640-01.dmp/file

EDIT: please i just need someone to view the dmp file with windbg because i dont have it

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-7-blue-screen-stop-0x0000003b/2fe23544-8073-4edb-b9b4-0ffa00530192

Comment: What is more helpful is the output of WinDBG.

Comment: Have you installed any new driver or Windows Update or product?

Comment: Is your system overclocked?

Comment: oh my god!! NO ITS NOT